# How to know that an AUSampler is playing?

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio, audiounit

Any way to know if an AUSampler contained in an AUGraph is producing any sound ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

1. If you can hear the output
2. If you attach a render callback and can see the audio data is not all 0's
3. If you run the output of the sampler into a mixer unit and turn on volume metering and have a volume level